# Implementing scrolling in a CWnd with multiple CWnd Children

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using the ScrollHelper [1] code to try and implement scrolling in my CWnd (ProgressListWnd) object. Within this CWnd, I have multiple child CWnd objects (ProgressWnd) being placed within the parent ProgressListWnd. Everything I've found is working with images or text / shapes being drawn in a CWnd rather than only dealing with a parent CWnd with child CWnds.

Implementing the ScrollHelper seems to "work", but my issue is within my OnPaint in the ProgressListWnd, I re-position each child object. I read that when an OnScroll is called, it ends with sending a paint event to the window. Since I start at 0,0 and re-position children downwards, nothing appears to move.

My onPaint for the parent window is below. Anything scrollbar related is directly from the ScrollHelper class.

Is there an easier way for scrolling in a CWnd that is only going to consist of children CWnd objects? Do I need to manually keep track of scroll positions and MoveWindow() on my children CWnds to negative positions when repainting (which will be necessary when adding or removing children)?

[1]

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10902/Add-Scrolling-to-a-CWnd-or-CDialog-using-a-C-Helpe

```
void CProgressListWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    POSITION pos = m_ProgressMap.GetStartPosition();
    int corner = 0;
    while(pos != NULL)
    {
        int uid = 0;
        CProgressWnd* pWnd = NULL;
        m_ProgressMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, uid, pWnd);
        if(pWnd != NULL)
        {
            pWnd->MoveWindow(0,corner,400,90);
            corner = corner + 90;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've tried moving my OnPaint logic to another method to only get called when adding / removing my children. Technically this works... however I'm running into the issue where when I re-position everything, 0,0 is the corner even if the area is scrolled. So I guess I can either reset the scrollbars' positions to 0, or (if this is even possible) set the corner to 0 minus scrollbar position. This would be a negative coordinate, not sure if that's allowed. I'm guessing I'm overthinking this?

Comment: better not reset the scrollbar position, otherwise there's no visual cue to "where" you are -- negative co-ordinates are allowed, you should maybe clip the painting to top=0 left=0

Comment: @EdwardClements So should I keep my re-positioning in the OnPaint and clip? Or something else? Do you have a link to an example I could look  over?

Comment: sorry, I don't have a sample code to hand -- it might actually be even easier than what I suggested -- not reset the scrollbar, derive the home position of your painting from the scrollbar position and just paint; from what I remember, `OnPaint` for a control should automatically clip the painting using the coordinates of the control -- can you try this out and see what happens?

Comment: @EdwardClements So I figured out a "hackish" way to get exactly what I want. Apparently using MoveWindow() does accept negative positions, so I can just take the position minus how many pixels the area is shifted from scrolling. I'll post my code later for anyone else who runs into this.